# count word with star on php

Tags: php

I have a code to count words with a star character, the result that I have like this:

```
Sentence "Today is Monday" have :
Count word = 3 word
Word-1 :Today
Word-2 :is
Word-3 :Monday
```

and the source code:

```
<?php
$sentence = "Today is Monday";
$word=explode(" ", $sentence);
$count = count(explode(" ", $sentence));
//$count2 = count(explode(" ", $word));
echo "Sentence <b>\"".$sentence."\"</b> have : <br>";
echo "Count word = $count<br>\n";
echo "Word-1 :".$word[0]."<br>";
echo "Word-2 :".$word[1]."<br>";
echo "Word-3 :".$word[2]."<br>";
?>
```

and the result, that i want like this:

```
Today is Monday
count word = 3 word

* * * * * = Today
* * = is
* * * * * * = Monday
```

Comment: `echo str_repeat('* ', strlen($word[0])) . "= ".$word[0]."<br>";`

Comment: Why explode $sentence twice? `$word=explode(" ", $sentence);
$count = count($word);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
$sentence = "Today is Monday";
$word=explode(" ", $sentence);
$count = count(explode(" ", $sentence));
//$count2 = count(explode(" ", $word));
echo "Sentence <b>\"".$sentence."\"</b> have : <br>";
echo "Count word = $count<br>\n";
echo str_repeat('*', strlen($word[0])) . " = " . $word[0] . "<br>";
echo str_repeat('*', strlen($word[1])) . " = " . $word[1] . "<br>";
echo str_repeat('*', strlen($word[2])) . " = " . $word[2] . "<br>";
```

**Output:**

```
Sentence "Today is Monday" have :
Count word = 3
***** = Today
** = is
****** = Monday
```

Comment: Please use above code it will giving same output as you required. @Dini Dwi Rahayu

Comment: Please give your feedback. @Dini Dwi Rahayu

Answer (score 0):

The [str_repeat](http://php.net/str_repeat) and [strlen](http://php.net/strlen) functions should help you do that:

```
foreach ($word as $w) {
    echo sprintf('%s = %s<br>', str_repeat('* ', strlen($w)), $w);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
 <?php $sentence = "Today is Monday";
 $word=explode(" ", $sentence);
 $count = sizeof($word);
 echo "Sentence <b>\"".$sentence."\"</b> have : <br>";
 echo "Count word = $count<br>\n";
 $i=0;
 while($i<$count){
 echo str_repeat('*', strlen($word[$i])) . " = " . $word[$i] . "<br>";
 $i++;
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best but work as expected

```
function star($word){
    for ($x = 1; $x <= strlen($word); $x++) {
        $star[] = "*";
    }
    return implode("",$star)." = ".$word;
}

$sentence = "Today is Monday";
$word=explode(" ", $sentence);
$count = count(explode(" ", $sentence));
//$count2 = count(explode(" ", $word));
echo "Sentence <b>\"".$sentence."\"</b> have : <br>";
echo "Count word = $count<br>\n";
foreach($word as $words){
    echo star($words)."<br>";
}
```

http://ideone.com/6ct5rl

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion could be

```
<?php
    $sentence = "Today is Monday";
    $arrayWords = explode(" ", $sentence);
    $cptWords = count($arrayWords);
    $showAnswer = "Count word = $cptWords word";
    if($cptWords>1)  $showAnswer.= "s"; //add "s to "word" if more than 1 word in $sentence
    $showAnswer .= "<br />";
    $currentStarWord = "";    
    //embolding one word in two
    for($i=0; $i<$cptWords; $i++){
        if($i%2==0) echo "<strong>$arrayWords[$i]</strong> ";
        else echo $arrayWords[$i]." ";
    }
    echo "<br />";    
    echo "$showAnswer<br />";
    for($i=0; $i<$cptWords; $i++){
        for($j=0; $j<strlen($arrayWords[$i]); $j++){ 
            $currentStarWord .= "*";
        }
        echo "$currentStarWord = <strong>$arrayWords[$i]</strong><br />";
        $currentStarWord = "";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

    function replaceWithCharacter($s, $character='* ')
    {
        return str_repeat($character, strlen($s));
    }

    $sentence = 'Today is monday';
    $words = str_word_count($sentence, 1);
    $x = array_map('replaceWithCharacter', $words);
    $len = count($words);
    echo $sentence."\n";

    echo sprintf("count word = %d word%s\n\n", $len, (1 < $len ? 's' : ''));

    for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        echo sprintf("%s = %s\n", $x[$i], $words[$i]);
    }
```